# Постоянно чистится база

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет.
Возникла проблема.
Написал движек и запустил в сеть.
Фильтрирую все запросы в бд.
Но кто-то удаляет все данные из базы подчистую все таблицы пользователя.
Как можно с этим справится?

Comment: в логах не написано кто?

Comment: Логи чистые сразу, хотя на домене они включены

Comment: База где нахрдится??? хостинг?

Comment: А какая разница где? Хостинг надежный)

Comment: это вопрос как бы был ) если хостинг нормальный, то пишите в сапорт - там и посмотрят и ответят что может быть. Возможно это приколы хостинга....а может у вас что то включено - а вы не знаете )

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, но скорее кто-то проворонил либо sql injection, либо аутентификацию и проверку прав (а ещё тип запросов) и какой-нибудь гугл поисковым ботом сносит всю базу.

Comment: @Qwertiy он говорит что и логов нет, гугл не может же логи  снести

Comment: А как обезопасить себя от такого?

Comment: все таки разберитесь с логами - чтобы они писались так чтобы точно не могли удалиться. И проверьте сами - сможете ли удалить через SQL injection что-то?

Comment: Оказалось , что дело было в скрытых лимитах хостинга.